# Replace a text box with a placeholder (Title or Body)

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes, slide

I received a PowerPoint file with multiple slides which were supposed to be templates (designs - customlayouts) but instead were regular slides.

Transforming them into SlideMaster and custom layouts and replacing the titles and bodys (textboxes) with actual placeholders by hand was a pain.

So I came with this script to make the process faster.

If anybody has a better approach, it's welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Had to look for a workaround to get the `customlayout` object.

Several things are missing, for example error handling.

To test it, copy a textbox into a slidemaster layout slide, select it and run the ReplaceWithPHTitle macro

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReplaceWithPHTitle()

    ReplaceTexboxWithPlaceholder ppPlaceholderTitle

End Sub

Public Sub ReplaceWithPHBody()

    ReplaceTexboxWithPlaceholder ppPlaceholderBody

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceTexboxWithPlaceholder(ByVal placeholderType As PpPlaceholderType)

    Dim targetLayout As CustomLayout
    Dim activeShape As Shape
    Dim newPlaceHolder As Shape
    
    Set activeShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    Set targetLayout = activeShape.Parent
    
    Set newPlaceHolder = targetLayout.Shapes.AddPlaceholder(Type:=placeholderType, Left:=activeShape.Left, Top:=activeShape.Top, Width:=activeShape.Width + 15, Height:=activeShape.Height)
    
    With newPlaceHolder.TextFrame

        .TextRange.Font.Name = activeShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name
        .TextRange.Characters.Font.Color.RGB = activeShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Font.Color.RGB
        .TextRange.Font.Size = activeShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size
        .TextRange.Font.Bold = activeShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold
        .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type = activeShape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type
        .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceWithin = activeShape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceWithin
        .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = activeShape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment
        .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = activeShape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore
        .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = activeShape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter
        .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.BaseLineAlignment = activeShape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.BaseLineAlignment
        .TextRange.Text = activeShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    End With
    
    With newPlaceHolder.TextFrame2
        .TextRange.Font.Spacing = activeShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing
    End With
    
    newPlaceHolder.ZOrder msoSendToBack
    newPlaceHolder.Select
    
End Sub
```

Any improvements are welcome too.